# Is it necessary to write title,html,head tag in ajax requested page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page welcome.htm which is loaded in another page via ajax

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Welcome</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

</head>

<body>
Welcome
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me the extremely necessary tags to include in this page so i can make my code short

Comment: The only mandatory tag is title, the html, body and head tags are optional, as is DOCTYPE. But having a DOCTYPE is important for other reasons. Note that html, head and body *elements* are required, it's the tags that are optional, so if you omit the tags the browser will put the required elements where it thinks they should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that If you have `html,body,head` tags in your response and when you append the response in any element (div) on the page where the request came from. It automatically gets removed. You can test this scenario by fetching the content you just loaded inside a div tag.

So its better to have necessary css files, scripts into your parent page.

Answer (score 1):

If it's using the same stylesheets and scripts you could just transfer the body and replace that via the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need any Headerfiles if you just fetch some data.
Get a look on this Link: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp
So you just response with "pure text" and format is with you script after it.
I always prefer this way, because the you keep the traffic as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Html, head, title, scripts ... tags in the page which does the ajax call. U just need the body content, in your case the text "Welcome" is only what you need from the ajax call.